# Collecting data from MySQL connected tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables in MySQL.

```
         +-----------------------------------------------+
Table 2  |                                       Table 1 |
+============+=========+========+============+   +==========+=====================+
|     ID     |   Name  |  Add   |    d_id    |   |   ID     |     Details         |
+============+=========+========+============+   +==========+=====================+
|     1      |    ABC  |  City  |     3      |   |    1     |    blah blah blah   |
+------------+---------+--------+------------+   +----------+---------------------+
:            :         :        :            :   :          :                     :
                                    |
          +-------------------------+
          |
Table 3   |                                    Table 4
+============+==========+============+         +=========+======================+      
|    d_id    | dis_Name |  cat_id    |----+    | cat_id  |    category_name     |
+============+==========+============+    |    +=========+======================+
|     1      | Myeloma  |     5      |    |    :         :                      :     
+------------+----------+------------+    |    +---------+----------------------+
:            :          :            :    +----|    5    |       Cancer         |
                                               +---------+----------------------+
```

What I want to do is, I want to select all the rows in 'Table 1' those belongs to the 'category_name' in 'Table 4'.
Table 2 may contain multiple rows having same 'd_id'. Likewise, Table 3 may have multiple rows having same 'cat_id'.
If I select Category 'Cancer' then I would be getting multiple d_id's from table 3 in result. For each d_id, there will be multiple ID's in table 2. I want to fetch the details of these ID's (from Table 2) from Table 1. What would be the query statement???

Connectivity is shown in the table representaion.

Comment: Could you just show us an example result set instead of making us figure out the links between the tables. That would be way more obvious :)

Comment: @Ignas Hiii... I just want to know the path through which I can fetch information from Table 1 using Table 4. What can be the select statement? This will be like a treeview, you just grab the stem and count the number of leaves :)

Comment: is d_id the ID in table 1? I don't think the logical structure of your tables is right (i may be wrong, it's quite late) nor the column names are obvious for us to figure out the relationships.

Comment: @Ignas Table 1 is connected to only Table 2 with ID column. Table 2 and Table 3 are only connected with d_id column and Table 3 and Table 4 are connected through cat_id column. I think now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it doing this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t4
INNER JOIN t3 ON (t4.cat_id = t3.cat_id)
INNER JOIN t2 ON (t3.d_id = t2.d_id)
INNER JOIN t1 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
WHERE t4.category_name = 'Cancer';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a join.

```
SELECT table.column_in_table
FROM table
INNER JOIN table_with_same_values
ON table.column_in_table = table_with_same_values.column_in_that_table;
```

I'm still not clear what you're trying to ask. Your question is a bit verbose. Some additional info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hiii I'm not trying to join the data in these tables. I want to fetch information from only one table. For example, you are the manager, 4 HR managers are working under you and each HR manager controls a group of 10 workers. Now I want to know the details of workers (not HR managers) indirectly working under you.